# Is there any way to for an iPhone app to require iPhone 5 or newer?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, screen-size, arm64

I am in the apparently not-common situation of wanting to deploy a new iPhone-only app and would love to require iPhone 5 or newer.  That is, 4" screen or greater.  I believe there is no way to accomplish that but though it was worth asking.

Requiring iOS 8 would be one way to get *close* but people can also run the app on iPhone 4s if they are a glutton for punishment and run iOS 8 on a 4s.  Plus I would like to support iOS 7.

One other thought is to build ONLY for arm64.  But I can't find anyone who has done that and I have to wonder if the app would be rejected.

Can anyone confirm or deny that this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really an explicit way to prevent a specific device from seeing your app on the app store, but you can use `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in your Info.plist file to implicitly filter out devices by requiring capabilities:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3